# Draw dynamically images in different div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

Hello I have a form with four divs, every div is a full page to print like this one:

[image: Format Example]

I create all the controls with AJAX no problem with that, then I load the images with another ajax call, here is the success function:

```
success: function (data) {
        //Variable para convertir los datos obtenidos a JSON
        var aRC = JSON.parse(data.d);
        //Variable que se utilizara para construir la estructura HTML
        var lineas = "";
        var lineas2 = "";
        //Ciclo FOR para recorrer el arreglo
        for (var i = 0; i < aRC.length; i++) {
            //Variables = a campos obtenidos al ejecutar la funcion
            var id = aRC[i].Id;
            var num = id;
            var rev = aRC[i].FileName;
            var pur = aRC[i].Type;
            var status = aRC[i].Content;
            var imagen = status.substring(36, status.length - 37);
            var owner = aRC[i].IdAlerta;


            if (i < 4) {
                lineas += '<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-xs-3 thumb marco">';
                lineas += '<a class="thumbnail" href="#">'
                lineas += '<img class="responsive" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,' + imagen + '" />';
                lineas += '<p class="hidden text-justify" id="Pie' + i + '"></p>'
                lineas += '</a>';
                lineas += '<span class="btn btn-xs btn-success fa fa-pencil hidden-print" id="EditPie' + i + '"></span>';
                lineas += '<input type="text" class="form-control hidden hidden-print" id="PiePag' + i + '"> <span class="btn btn-xs btn-success fa fa-check hidden hidden-print" id="OkPie' + i + '"></span>'
                lineas += '</div>';
            }

            else {

                lineas2 += '<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-xs-3 thumb marco">';
                lineas2 += '<a class="thumbnail" href="#">'
                lineas2 += '<img class="responsive" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,' + imagen + '" />';
                lineas2 += '<p class="hidden text-justify" id="Pie' + i + '"></p>'
                lineas2 += '</a>';
                lineas2 += '<span class="btn btn-xs btn-success fa fa-pencil hidden-print" id="EditPie' + i + '"></span>';
                lineas2 += '<input type="text" class="form-control hidden hidden-print" id="PiePag' + i + '"> <span class="btn btn-xs btn-success fa fa-check hidden hidden-print" id="OkPie' + i + '"></span>'
                lineas2 += '</div>';
            }
        }
        $('#Imagenes').html(lineas);
        $('#Imagenes2').html(lineas2);
    }
```

The problem here is that I want to load only 4 images per page, my current code its wrong but works with less than 9 images how can I solve this?

PD. That code is only for 2 pages, but has to work with more than 2.

EDIT: $Imagenes is a div(page1), $Imagenes2 is another div(page2).

Comment: What do you mean by "every div is a full page" ? Can you attach a fiddle ?

Comment: For example print.html, have <div id="page1">, <div id="page2"> and with ajax I draw the format like in the image that is a full page, and I cant attach a fiddle because I do all with ajax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just continue with your "IF" like this:

```
if (i < 4) {
   code for $('#Imagenes')
}
else {
   if (i < 8) {
      code for $('#Imagenes2')           
   }
   else {
         if (i < 12) { 
              code for $('#Imagenes3')          
         }
   }
}
```

And continue doing that with all the #Imagenes you want.